# Remove character from a list made of a data in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, file, arraylist

Well I have a file with this data on it:

1. Jesus Rodriguez, 5 E 5.2 1.7
2. Luka Zorichk, 21 P 11.2 4.8
3. Jorge Campillons, 15 L 7 3.3

And more data.. Each line has a name, the numbers, the position they play, number of points and the ratio of rebounds ("Jesus Rodriguez", "5", "E", "5.2", "1.7").

Okey the problem that I have is when I get the data from the file, and the name is added to the list with a comma and I do not want that character on it. Here's the code that I have for now:

```
def leeFich(f):
    listaDatos = list()
    d = open(f)
    for lin in d:
        listaDatos.append(lin.strip())
        for i in listaDatos:
            i.replace(',', ' ') // Here is what I have tried to remove the comma
    return(listaDatos)

print(leeFich("ligaBaloncesto.txt"))
```

And the output still has the comma in the first item in the list that I just made.

> Output:['Jesus Rodriguez, 5 E 5.2 1.7', 'Luka Zorichk, 21 P 11.2 4.8', 'Jorge Campillons, 15 L 7 3.3', '']
>
> Expected Output:['Jesus Rodriguez 5 E 5.2 1.7', 'Luka Zorichk, 21 P 11.2 4.8', 'Jorge Campillons, 15 L 7 3.3', '']

Comment: Can you paste the output in formatted text, rather than images? Also, add expected output.

Comment: Already done! thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `str.replace` doesn't work in-place. Besides, you can perform the replacing on few lines above while you strip the line. Secondly, for reading a file object it's better to use `with` statement that closes the file at the end of the block and doesn't open the chance of memory leak for you. Thirdly, instead of creating a list and calling the `append` attribute on it at each loop you can simple create your list using a list comprehension.

```
def leeFich(f):
    with open(f) as d:
        lista_datos = [lin.strip().replace(',', '') for lin in d]
    return list_dataos
```

Comment: Perfect! Didn't know it can be done that way! thanks a lot :)